# JS regex to match URL except if it's in single or double quotes

Tags: regex

This matches URLs so that I can linkify them:

```
(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-._+]@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]\b|\b([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/|[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/www\.|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]([:]*[0-9]*)(\/[-~+=%!:#@_a-zA-Z0-9.]*[-~+=:%!#_a-zA-Z0-9])*\/?(\/?\?[-+=&;:%@_.a-zA-Z0-9]*[-+=:&;%@_a-zA-Z0-9])?(#[-=_a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)
```

But I want to avoid matching URLs that are in HTML e.g. `<img src="http://foo.com"/>`.

My thought was to update the regex so that it did *not* match if the URL was surrounded by single or double quotes. I think this would nicely cover all cases where the URL was in an HTML attribute and therefore shouldn't be mucked with.

How do I achieve this in JS regex?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use negative lookahead and lookbehind assertions, but for js negative lookahead doesn't work. So maybe negative lookbehind assertion would be enough.

I would suggest to use already existing pattern (from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)) for example:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

And modify it a bit adding: `\w(?!\")` so the URL finishes with letter followed by **not** double quotes.

You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/hY8sZ8/1

Comment: Cool. Alas, it doesn't cover all the cases I incorporated into the original regex in my question, e.g. query strings and whatnot. Hrm.